# PDO::exec() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given when using prepared statements

Tags: php, sql, security, prepared-statement

I am trying to protect against SQL-injections by using prepared statements.

The following code shows the function that is called when a new user is created. The code that is commented out did work but was unsafe. Therefore, I tried changing it, but am getting the following error:

> PDO::exec() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given

Here is the code:

```
function save()
{
    if ($this->id === null) {
        $query = self::$app->db->prepare(self::INSERT_QUERY);
        $query->bindParam(1, $this->username);
        $query->bindParam(2, $this->password);
        $query->bindParam(3, $this->email);
        $query->bindParam(4, $this->bio);
        $query->bindParam(5, $this->isAdmin);

        //$query = sprintf(self::INSERT_QUERY,
         //   $this->username,
         //   $this->password,
         //   $this->email,
         //   $this->bio,
         //   $this->isAdmin            );
    } else {
      $query = sprintf(self::UPDATE_QUERY,
            $this->username,
            $this->password,
            $this->email,
            $this->bio,
            $this->isAdmin,
            $this->id
        );
    }

    return self::$app->db->exec($query);
}
```

I am really new to both PHP and security, so any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `prepare()` returns a statement object, `exec()` expects a statement string. You should use [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php), which expects a statement object

Comment: which condition is executed? the `if` or the `else` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`PDO::prepare`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) method returns a [`PDOStatement`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object (not a string value). You need to use the [`PDOStatement::execute`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) method to execute the prepared statement:

```
$query = self::$app->db->prepare(self::INSERT_QUERY);
$query->bindParam(1, $this->username);
$query->bindParam(2, $this->password);
$query->bindParam(3, $this->email);
$query->bindParam(4, $this->bio);
$query->bindParam(5, $this->isAdmin);
$query->execute(); //execute the prepared statement.
```

With [`PDO::exec`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) you can only execute a SQL statement (without binding parameters).

---

You are mixing prepared statements and SQL statements. You should use the following:

```
function save()
{
    if ($this->id === null) {
        $query = self::$app->db->prepare(self::INSERT_QUERY);
        $query->bindParam(1, $this->username);
        $query->bindParam(2, $this->password);
        $query->bindParam(3, $this->email);
        $query->bindParam(4, $this->bio);
        $query->bindParam(5, $this->isAdmin);
        return $query->execute();
    } else {
        $query = self::$app->db->prepare(self::UPDATE_QUERY);
        $query->bindParam(1, $this->username);
        $query->bindParam(2, $this->password);
        $query->bindParam(3, $this->email);
        $query->bindParam(4, $this->bio);
        $query->bindParam(5, $this->isAdmin);
        $query->bindParam(6, $this->id);
        return $query->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! Unfortunately, that gave another error (I tried it before): 
"
Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::execute() in /***/User.php on line 70"

For some reason the execute() method is not recognized, it seems

Comment: `var_dump($query)`?

Comment: Hi! Thank you again, actually, it did work when I used your code. I get another error now:
"General error: 25 bind or column index out of range" on the line where the first "return $query->execute();" is

Comment: Can you show the queries (`INSERT_QUERY` and `UPDATE_QUERY`)? looks like you try to bind more parameters then available.

Comment: Oh, the mistake was somewhere else :) I used %s instead of ? in INSERT_QUERY. Thank you for your patience! You are awesome!